# Resolve broken symbolic links without checking for existance

Tags: java, linux, symlink, file-descriptor

I have an issue with my Java webapp: it fails after few days with error `FileSystemException: Too many open files`. I understand what it means, but I can't figure out where I didn't close the file. So I'm trying to write some debug code to help me find the reason of this error: this code is supposed to return all file descriptors (and shows it via debug http endpoint):

```java
Files.list(Paths.get(String.format("/proc/$d/fd", pid))).map(
  fd -> String.format(
    "%s:%s",
    fd.getFileName(),
    // also I tried fd.toRealPath()
    fd.toFile().getCanonicalFile()
  )
).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But this code doesn't show broken links (symbolic links where target was removed). `Path.toRealPath()` fails with `NoSuchFileException` here, `Path.toFile().getCanonicalPath()` ignores such links and doesn't show the target. Only system `ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/` works correctly and resolve all links.

Is it possible to resolve such links using Java (1.8 JDK)?

Comment: If `toRealPath()` consistently fails on broken links, then why not just catch the exception and use it in order to detect whether the link is fine or not? It has been a long time since I tried to use symbolic links in Java and back then it was a nightmare because they were not supported in Java. Maybe things changed but since this is only for debugging, IMO using the exception is fine? By the way, there are some tools that look for leaking file descriptors, for example valgrind. valgrind with Java is not easy but maybe there are similar tools for Java?

Comment: Just found that you can read the target of a symbolic link in java, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html

Comment: @DanielJunglas thanks, this `Files.readSymbolicLink` function works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, I can see two options to figure out whether a file is a dead symbolic link:

1. Use `Files.readSymbolicLink()` and then check whether the target exists.
2. Use `Files.exists()` with different options: If the file exists with `NOFOLLOW_LINKS` but does not exist without that option then it should be a dangling symbolic link.